# Make it unable to work in mainscreen when popup is open?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup

I am implementing an application, and when you start this application, you have a main screen maximized over the whole screen, but also a popup appears. I want that as long as my pop up isn't closed, the user can't do anything in the main screen behind this popup (like when you have an error message or something)? It is probably some property but can't find it out. Someone who can help me out please? I am working in WPF and C#.

Comment: this is called a modal dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popups are not not meant for this sort of thing i think. You can just use a normal `Window` and [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) to get a modal popup. If you don't want the frame and everything you can style it respectively by setting [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) to `true` and [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) to `None`.

Comment: But i do this in my window loaded of my main screen:
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            ToetsBeheerViewModel toetsBeheerViewModel = new ToetsBeheerViewModel();

            ToetsBeheerView.DataContext = toetsBeheerViewModel;

         
            EditAlgemeneGegevens window = new EditAlgemeneGegevens(toetsBeheerViewModel.Examination);
            window.Show();
         
        }

What should i do then?

Comment: Oops i get it, in fact of window.Show it must be window.ShowDialog. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Ruben: That is exactly what i wrote in my answer, did i not?